Why is an S3 object available via HTTP (no S3 API protocol) when not expected?
After about 10 years dealing with S3, I feel like I maybe missed something. I have a particular case where:

URLs like
https://<bucket-name>.s3.<region>.amazonaws.com/<object-key> are
serving up objects via HTTP.
objects were written using the "public-read" ACL
bucket Object Ownership = Object writer, ACLs are enabled
bucket Static website hosting is disabled.
obviously pre-signed URLs are not involved.
CloudFront distribution is enabled for a narrow prefix path on this bucket that does not match the object keys I can retrieve.

I would expect that objects given public-read ACL can be freely accessed by anyone, unauthenticated with AWS, using the AWS API for GetObject. I do not expect this http access behavior, however. Even if Static website hosting were enabled, the URL would be different.

Is it the HTTP vs HTTPS behavior that surprises you?  If you look up the docs for S3 static websites, direct bucket access only supports HTTP.  For HTTPS you need CloudFront.

You're thinking Static Web Hosting allows HTTP access but what it does is enables Route53 to point to the bucket and serve files.  When you apply the Public ACL to a bucket (w/ no WebSite Hosting) eg: https://azuretrainingforncg.s3.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/Demo+Steps.txt its makes files available via a HTTP GET as well as AWS CLI GetObject. It doesn't matter if its static web hosted either, eg https://s3.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/jeremythompson.net/logo192.png is the same as https://jeremythompson.net/logo192.png and via CloudFront https://deixr339d3zu0.cloudfront.net/logo192.png

Without any params, or signing, the S3 GetObject API is in fact the same as a normal HTTPS GET request.

@DaveS - thanks for the comment. As I said, Static web hosting is disabled.

@JeremyThompson - thanks for the comment. The Public ACL is not applied to the bucket, just particular objects. Static web hosting is disabled. I understand your point about Static web hosting creating a new DNS hostname, so Route53 territory, but Route 53 is not serving the files. S3 must be doing that. But, I am not following what you are saying with your example of the logo192.png. You are telling me you have a bucket named "s3" and it is no Static website hosted. Of course, I can't verify that. But, I would really like to see where this behavior is documented.

@AnonCoward - thanks for your comment. As I read it, GetObject requires specific parameters which are not included in the simple GET requests that I see return objects.
GET /Key+?partNumber=PartNumber&response-cache-control=ResponseCacheControl&response-content-disposition=ResponseContentDisposition&response-content-encoding=ResponseContentEncoding&response-content-language=ResponseContentLanguage&response-content-type=Resp...
The documentation does not state these parameters are optional. I suppose if they all were, it would reduce to be sufficient to just supply the key.

S3 documentation documents the required parameters.  All non-required parameters are optional.  In the case of GetObject, only the Key itself is required, everything else is optional.

@AnonCoward - feel free to write up as an answer if you would like credit for such.

The S3 API is implemented as a series of REST API calls (along with SOAP API calls for backwards compatibility reasons).  Specifically, if we go through the documentation for the GetObject call and remove each item that's not marked as required, we're left with a call like this:
GET /Key HTTP/1.1
Host: Bucket.s3.amazonaws.com

In other words, a normal HTTPS GET request that any user agent like a browser would send.  The user agent will include other headers, but S3 will ignore those headers it doesn't directly support.
So, assuming an object does not require the authorization header since it has public-read ACL, then a browser will load it directly as if it's making a GetObject call, since in effect, it is.

Great explanation breaking it down to the core HTTP call.
